# Directory Listing disabled despite Options +Indexes in configuration

Tags: debian, apache-virtualhost

I have 3 vhosts on a server, I want one of them to have directory listing enabled. This is the configuration file for it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName me
        ServerAdmin me
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test.host.net
        <Directory "/var/www/test.host.net">
                Options All +Indexes
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
        #<Directory /var/www/>
        #        Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        #        AllowOverride all
        #        Order allow,deny
        #        allow from all
        #</Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errors_from_this_host.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_to_this_host.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The file does have directory handling for /var/www/ but since it's commented out I believe it is disabled.

I have an .htaccess file in /var/www/test.host.net with Options +Indexes just in case.

Error log:

`[error] [client dumb] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/test.host.net/`

Issue is occurring on Debian 7 Apache 2.2

All suggestions welcome.

Comment: What does `All` do on the `Options` line?

Comment: The apache2 manual says: `Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax and will be rejected during server startup by the syntax check with an abort.`

Comment: Where is it mixed in the configuration above? Restarting apache does not return any error messages at all.

Comment: Still, I'd guess it doesn't like `Options All +Indexes`; maybe split it into two lines `Options All` and `Options +Indexes`.

Comment: btw. the 2.2 documentation only says `Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax and is likely to cause unexpected results.`
And further, it looks like All includes Indexes, so you don't need that one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. However I did remove all instances of Options All and just left +Indexes present, still no go. Same error message and behavior. Is there a way where I can see where exactly is this directive (Options -Indexes) specified? I searched through all config files in /etc/apache and none of them have Options -Indexes present or Options All.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.

Never, ever leave any files in your sites-enabled directory - I had an old vhost configuration file that was saved as host.bck, which for some reason was being read by Apache, and it executed the configuration in it for all vhosts... basically my configuration files weren't working at all up to when I found out this.

Comment: On Debian 8 (jessie) all Apache 2.4 configuration fragments must have `.conf` extension, exactly to combat this type of trouble.